# Safest Way to Link Google's TCMalloc lib

Tags: c++, c, windows, tcmalloc

After some days of test I figured out that the runtime patching mechanism [patch_functions.cc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gperftools/gperftools/master/src/windows/patch_functions.cc) is not safe to use in a production environment.

It seems to work well in a VS2010 project except for HeapAlloc() and HeapFree() but cannot be used in a VS2015 project due to some unresolved problems [Open Issues](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20VS2015).
the windows readme describes this alternative way to use tcmalloc:

---

*An alternative to all the above is to statically link your application
with libc, and then replace its malloc with tcmalloc.  This allows you
to just build and link your program normally; the tcmalloc support
comes in a post-processing step.  This is more reliable than the above
technique (which depends on run-time patching, which is inherently
fragile), though more work to set up.  For details, see
   https://groups.google.com/group/google-perftools/browse_thread/thread/41cd3710af85e57b*

---

Unfortunately the provided lik is urechable, seems that google had closed the group. 
Could someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it suggests to write your own `malloc` which uses `tcmalloc`.

So you have to *define* and link your own one (by creating or using an .c aka translation unit) and write something like this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>

void* malloc(size_t size) {
    return tcmalloc(size);
}

//Also define a free if memory which has been allocated by tcmalloc 
//needs to be freed by a special function
// Like 
/*
void free(void* ptr) {
    if (ptr) {
        tcfree(ptr);
    }
}
*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Problem is: Depending on your building system or linker, it may nag about double symbols aka references. Then you have to somehow exclude libcs `malloc`, or change the libc by yourself.

Comment: Useful but not considerable as a full answer

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this as well and believe I found a way to have it working.

First, in `windows\config.h`, you have to replace

```
#undef WIN32_OVERRIDE_ALLOCATORS
```

by

```
#define WIN32_OVERRIDE_ALLOCATORS
```

Then, and it's the most important thing, you have to make sure of two things:

1. `windows\patch_functions.cc` is not compiled and linked
2. `windows\overridde_functions.cc` is compiled and linked

At first, I omitted step 2 and got a barely functioning DLL where some memory allocations would get freed and overridden apparently at random.

In my case, making sure of both steps was just a matter of ensuring only `windows\override_functions.cc` is included in my `libtcmalloc` VS2017 project.